# Storing the id and data of potential teachers to whom I have already sent a message in the mongoose model

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm having trouble applying the right approach in the mongoose model. Case: There are no `teachers` selected yet in the `student` application. Would like to send messages to potential teachers. By going to the list of potential teachers, I can send them a private message. In the 'student' model, can I add the property 'messagesWith' and put only the 'id' of people I am writing with in the array? Moving on to the chat, I would like to view a list of people to whom I have already sent a message. Where to store information and what data (or just id) to whom I have already sent a message.

**User, teacher, student model**

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        maxLength: 32
    },
    surname: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        maxLength: 32
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    initials: String,
    hashed_password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    salt: String,
    role: {
        type: String
    },
    profilePicture: {
        data: String,
        default: ''
    },
    cloudinary_id: {
        type: String,
    },
    resetPasswordLink: {
        data: String,
        default: ''
    }
}, {timestamps: true});


const studentSchema = userSchema.clone();
studentSchema.add({
    messagesWith: [],
    teachers: []
});

const teacherSchema = userSchema.clone();
teacherSchema.add({
    isActiveTutor: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
  
    teachingLanguage:{
        type: Object
    },
    youtubeUrlId: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    }
});
```

**message model**

```
const messageSchema = new Schema({
    sender: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId
    },
    receiver: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId
    },
    msg: {type: String},
    viewed: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you just want to implement the models? Don't want to implement it in Express?

Comment: I would like to view a list of people to whom I have already sent a message. Where to store information and what data (or just id) to whom I have already sent a message. How implement it in model? Lists of people to whom I sent a message. I will need this later to fetch a list of tutors with whom I sent a message

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi. No. i think that better approach is separate collection 'messages' . I don't want a big objects tutor or student

Comment: in this approach if size of collections increase, every request with populate will take 10s

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi but If I add message property to tutor and student when collection increase every request will take more time

Comment: no, because you can search and get own data based on `_id` (is index) without populate, use of populate and join in mongoose increase request time , what we use NoSql db ?? if a simple search takes a long time, why we use it?

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi I have different question. I have two separate collections 'students' and 'tutors'. Is it correct approach?

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi. ???

Comment: yes it is, I wanna test in 20M record in two separate collection, with your approach (a model between student and tutors) and my approach(without middle model), after test, I tell you result, which one is better in find() request... but I know your approach has simple query for find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to implement models to resolve your problem...

Some people use the Nosql database like a reliatinal database,both of them on depend your requirments.Your requirments now are very low and both methods can be used easily.

You need to anticipate your types of reports so that you do not have problems in the future.Because for a large data volume, populate and join collection with aggregation, slows down.

Avoid linking Collection as much as possible to get the report you want with a find(especially on Indexed fields likes _id)

I created a project at Github tonight you can check the [messaging project](https://github.com/mohammadyaser/messaning) and wrote 4 apis for it, based on two model without reliational (student Model <--> teacher Model)and added postman in postman follder,(create student, create teacher, send message, get message reciervers of a student by student id)

you can run,review and test the project, if I have a free time I worte based on reliational data (student model<-->message model<-->teacher model)

**student data**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ffb8889905c523b70ec2977"),
    "name" : "st1",
    "surname" : "lastname1",
    "email" : "email1@test.com",
    "hashed_password" : "123",
    "role" : "user",
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "contentInfo" : {
                "viewed" : false,
                "msg" : "from student to a teacher from/studentId/to/teacherId",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-01-10T23:20:34.796Z")
            },
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ffb8bc223286f4934f2a013"),
            "receiver" : ObjectId("5ffb6d4934cf83268096b97f")
        }, 
        {
            "contentInfo" : {
                "viewed" : false,
                "msg" : "from student to a teacher from/studentId/to/teacherId",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-01-10T23:21:33.765Z")
            },
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ffb8bfd23286f4934f2a016"),
            "receiver" : ObjectId("5ffb8beb23286f4934f2a015")
        }, 
        {
            "contentInfo" : {
                "viewed" : false,
                "msg" : "from student to a teacher from/studentId/to/teacherId",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-01-10T23:25:43.099Z")
            },
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ffb8cf7641f2e2e78686961"),
            "receiver" : ObjectId("5ffb8cea641f2e2e78686960")
        }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-01-10T23:06:49.878Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-10T23:25:43.112Z"),
    "__v" : 3
}
```

**teacher data**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ffb8beb23286f4934f2a015"),
    "isActiveTutor" : false,
    "youtubeUrlId" : "",
    "name" : "t1",
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "contentInfo" : {
                "viewed" : false,
                "msg" : "from student to a teacher from/studentId/to/teacherId",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-01-10T23:21:33.784Z")
            },
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ffb8bfd23286f4934f2a017"),
            "sender" : ObjectId("5ffb8889905c523b70ec2977")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 1
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ffb8cea641f2e2e78686960"),
    "isActiveTutor" : false,
    "youtubeUrlId" : "",
    "name" : "t2",
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "contentInfo" : {
                "viewed" : false,
                "msg" : "from student to a teacher from/studentId/to/teacherId",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-01-10T23:25:43.124Z")
            },
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ffb8cf7641f2e2e78686962"),
            "sender" : ObjectId("5ffb8889905c523b70ec2977")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 1
}
```

Comment: But when I send message from student to tutor, I have update two models in separate collections 'teachers' and 'students` and it will be problem for `return res.json()`. because I can't return two updated objects `student` and `tutor` in the same time

Comment: If you want update two collection, you must to use `transaction`, because if first update done and in second update an error  occur, rollback be done, but It's not a problem, there is a solution about this